# hand ros beginner

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could someone help me? I want to design a hand in gazebo that copies the movements of my hand,  Is there some tutorial for beginners? Or does anyone know how can i start? I'm using ros indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283994/hand-ros-beginner/) by [ANDRO](https://answers.ros.org/users/32353/andro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Follow `URDF` and `TF` tutorials.
You need to build a `URDF`  model for your hand and need to build a node to publish necessary `TF` (transformations) according to your input.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1